# Chess hourse move in a tic tac toe board

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I have an tic tac toe board (3x3 square board) and I need to make a move that is like the horse movement from chess.

Here is the rules:

- Start point that cannot be the center
- End point needs to be like the horse move in chess

So with this I have a formula that receives two inputs `x` and `y` which are the position of the starting point and the board and will return the new position when done the horse move.

I'm programming this, but instead of making a bunch of `if` and `else` to check all possibilites.

Is there an algebraic formula that given two inputs, return the new position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the positions $(x,y)$ have $x,y\in\{0,1,2\}$. Then to make a knight's move, we can go to the next position of the following knight's tour: $\left((0,0),(2,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,2),(0,1),(2,0),(1,2),(0,0)\right)$. A function that does that is $$\mathbf{v}(x,y)=\left(\dfrac14\left(8+x^2-8xy+y^2-x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2-y^3\right),\dfrac14\left(4+7x^2-7y^2-3x^3+2x^2y-2xy^2+3y^3\right)\right)\text{.}$$

For example $\mathbf{v}(2,1)$ should be either $(0,0)$ or $(0,2)$, and is $$\left(\dfrac14\left(8+2^2-8*2+1-2^3+2*2^2+2*2-1\right),\dfrac14\left(4+7*2^2-7-3*2^3+2*2^2-2*2+3\right)\right)$$
$$=\left(0,2\right)\text{.}$$

A function that gives the other move is given by almost a sort of rotation of the first function: $$\mathbf{w}(x,y)=\left(\dfrac14\left(4-7x^2+7y^2+3x^3-2x^2y+2xy^2-3y^3\right),\dfrac14\left(8+x^2-8xy+y^2-x^3+2x^2y+2xy^2-y^3\right)\right)\text{.}$$

These were found by simply asking a computer to solve for the coefficients of the polynomials that would do this.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I understand how you did it in teory, but I have no idea how you did this `asking a computer to solve for the coefficients of the polynomials`

Comment: @Vencovsky Some parts won't make sense if you don't know Mathematica code, but my approach was basically: [This one](https://tio.run/##rZBBi8IwEIXv/RUPFjzUoEl0112lP0EQPIZRgogrrFspVVpKf3udjLHi3Vzyzct7DzInX/7uT7487nzXHVy1Vai3hHkG7zRhyNeE0iqtBKcBa8FPSuuIX6xuJoIz8Ub9W9xx@BF/Wi@QlPmlQIamabSCbhUaq2DaAHdi4Bd7V4QYTPCKYp4p26dsTJk@ZaJH9x4de2zf80ixp01WxfG/dAl4DbwFwniEBFjnf9e9W/ozv/A5uA/njDJECkKWiJBlYbBBxkAh/JDlxTsq7Wtl190A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")